# Explanation of the cURL Windows build configurations

Tags: c++, windows, curl, libcurl

The cURL project contains a large amount of build configurations on Windows to choose from, but I cannot find a good overview description on what each configuration is for.

What is the purpose of the different parts of the build configurations for cURL?

The list of build configurations extracted from the VC15 solution file for cURL 7.63.0:

```
DLL Debug - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
DLL Debug - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
DLL Debug - DLL OpenSSL
DLL Debug - DLL OpenSSL
DLL Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
DLL Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
DLL Debug - DLL Windows SSPI
DLL Debug - DLL Windows SSPI
DLL Debug - DLL wolfSSL
DLL Debug - DLL wolfSSL
DLL Debug
DLL Debug
DLL Release - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
DLL Release - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
DLL Release - DLL OpenSSL
DLL Release - DLL OpenSSL
DLL Release - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
DLL Release - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
DLL Release - DLL Windows SSPI
DLL Release - DLL Windows SSPI
DLL Release - DLL wolfSSL
DLL Release - DLL wolfSSL
DLL Release
DLL Release
LIB Debug - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
LIB Debug - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
LIB Debug - DLL OpenSSL
LIB Debug - DLL OpenSSL
LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI
LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI
LIB Debug - LIB OpenSSL - LIB LibSSH2
LIB Debug - LIB OpenSSL - LIB LibSSH2
LIB Debug - LIB OpenSSL
LIB Debug - LIB OpenSSL
LIB Debug - LIB wolfSSL
LIB Debug - LIB wolfSSL
LIB Debug
LIB Debug
LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2
LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL
LIB Release - DLL OpenSSL
LIB Release - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
LIB Release - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN
LIB Release - DLL Windows SSPI
LIB Release - DLL Windows SSPI
LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL - LIB LibSSH2
LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL - LIB LibSSH2
LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL
LIB Release - LIB OpenSSL
LIB Release - LIB wolfSSL
LIB Release - LIB wolfSSL
LIB Release
LIB Release
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The leading `LIB` means building a static lib and `DLL` means make a DLL
- Debug/Release is for what sort of build to do
- LIB/DLL OpenSSL is for building libcurl with TLS support (for HTTPS etc) using OpenSSL as a lib or DLL
- LIB/DLL LibSSH2 is for building libcurl with SSH support using libssh2 as a lib or DLL
- `Windows SSPI` enables SSPI in the build, which is windows-specific magic for authentication
- DLL wolfSSL is for building libcurl with TLS support (for HTTPS etc) using wolfSSL (instead of OpenSSL)
- DLL WinIDN is for building libcurl with native windows IDN support enabled

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Stenberg, this makes it really clear! Hope you get a year with less emails regarding support requests from car infotainment users :)